# [UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, uiimageview, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I have a subclass of UIImageView which periodically refreshes itself to different images. I used the code below without any problem:

```
UIImage *cachedImage = [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromKey:blobKey];
if(cachedImage==nil) {
    NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    cachedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:cachedImage imageData:imageData forKey:blobKey toDisk:YES];
} 
self.image=cachedImage;
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 2.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;    
[self.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

The problem is when I decide to use, instead of the code above, "block"-style animation as Apple suggests for iOS 4.0+:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    self.image=cachedImage;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // do something..
}];
```

After I applied the new code, I got the error message: "message sent to deallocated instance". (I have iOS 5.1 SDK and ARC enabled.) Is there any aspect of block programming I should learn?

Answer (score 1):

in my case making the image property nil after the animation block worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your cachedImage is being released before the block executes.  In your first example, you are setting self.image ( which will retain the image ) before executing the animation.  Try creating an additional UIImage holder property that simply retains the reference to the cachedImage so that it sticks around for when the block executes.

Comment: I tried to add an extra holder property as you suggested by calling `self.retainedImage=cachedImage` right before block execution. But still I got the message: -[UIViewAnimationState retain]: message sent to deallocated instance. (I added more code of how I created cachedImage in the original post.)